# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java

Хочу научиться писать на java.

Нашел в интернете статью [основы Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/edu/j-introtojava1/section8.html#listing7). Делаю как указано в учебнике, но мне выдает ошибку:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>     Logger cannot be resolved to a type
>     Logger cannot be resolved
>     at com.makotogroup.intro.Person.main(Person.java:35)`

Текст программы:

```
package com.makotogroup.intro;

public class Person {

public Person(String name, int age, int height, int weight, String eyeColor, 
            String gender) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.height = height;
this.weight = weight;
this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
this.gender = gender;
}

      private String name;
      private int age;
      private int height;
      private int weight;
      private String eyeColor;
      private String gender;
      public Person() {
        // Делать больше нечего...
      }

    public Person(String name, int age, int height, String eyeColor, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
        this.gender = gender;
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person("Joe Q Author", 42, 173, 82, "Brown", "MALE");
          Logger l = Logger.getLogger(Person.class.getName());
          l.info("Name: " + p.getName());
          l.info("Age:" + p.getAge());
          l.info("Height (cm):" + p.getHeight());
          l.info("Weight (kg):" + p.getWeight());
          l.info("Eye Color:" + p.getEyeColor());
          l.info("Gender:" + p.getGender());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getEyeColor() {
        return eyeColor;
    }

    public void setEyeColor(String eyeColor) {
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте импорт библиотеки Logger. Вставьте этот код в самое начало файла:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

Comment: тоже самое...

Comment: там на сайте тоже у одного человека не получилось, но потом ошибку нашел: "Update: нашел ошибку. прошу прощения. я не тот Logger импортировал"